# Haskell - how to draw a map to a file accessing the buffer pixel by pixel

Tags: haskell, graphics, drawing, 2d

I am looking for a simple way to create an image, have the possibility to set the color of single pixels and later save this image as a png.

My goal is in particular to draw a map based on a content-generated world. The algorithms I am thinking to use require me to be able to set each single pixel independently, hopefully without having to copy the whole image each time I set a pixel.

What is the best (as in "most idiomatic") way to manipulate an image in this way using Haskell? Is it the right tool or should I use a C library for that instead?

**Note:** while I read questions somehow related, they were focusing on more complex frameworks to create entire game which is not my goal, I would rather use something lightweight

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be on-topic. On SO questions about software/library recommendations are *off-topic*. Even if you weren't asking for a library the question "How to create an image?" will definitely be closed as too broad. Consider posting this question on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (read carefully the help center before opening a question) or try to narrow down the topic of your question.

Comment: Thanks Bakuriu, I revised my question trying to address your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several other hours I have found this way to draw an image and save it as a PNG

```
import Codec.Picture

generateMap :: Image PixelRGB8
generateMap = generateImage f 512 512
              where f x y = PixelRGB8 0 0 0

main = do putStrLn "Start"
          let img = generateMap
          savePngImage "ciao.png" (ImageRGB8 img)
          putStrLn "Done"
```

It does not permit to set a single pixel individually after having generated the whole image but it is close enough for me. Hope it helps!